# What is the difference between Enable/Disable RLS and Grant/Revoke priviliges

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant, row-level-security

I have a table created by role A

```
Firstname|Lastname| Age
------------------------
 Jill    |  Smith |  50 
 Eve     |   Dar  |  94
```

Say I want to enable Row Level security,

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

this by default denies select/update/delete operations to all roles except the table owner(roleA and superuser)

Inorder to allow roleB to view/modify rows I would need to create a policy

```
CREATE POLICY view_users ON users TO roleB
    USING (manager = current_user);
```

That seems to me like GRANT/REVOKE privileges to a table, How is RLS different

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT` can only give permission on a complete table. Once you have GRANTed the `SELECT` privilege to a user (or role) that user can see **all** rows in the table, and if that user has the `UPDATE` privilege for the table, he/she can update **all** rows.

With RLS (as the name implies) you can control access for **each row** individually.

Given your example, granting SELECT privilege on the table will allow every user to see all rows. With your rule in place a user can only see rows of those employees where he/she is the manager (the rule should probably be extended to include the current user's row as well, not only those where the current user is the manager).

Take the following table:

```
Firstname | Lastname | manager 
------------------------------
Jill      | Smith    | paul
Eve       | Dar      | paul
Arthur    | Dent     | mary
Ford      | Prefect  | mary
```

If you grant select and update to the roles `mary` and `paul` they can see and change **all** rows in that table.

But with the RLS policy in your question, the role `mary` can only see and change Arthur Dent and Ford Prefect. And `paul` would only be able so see and change Jill Smith and Eve Dar.

Neither of those users would even know that there are more rows in the table.